# Which is correct way to get last inserted id in mysqli prepared statements procedural style?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

i am using mysqli prepared statement to insert record in the table like this

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

$code = 'DEU';
$language = 'Bavarian';
$official = "F";
$percent = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) > 0){
//if insert is successful then get the insrted id.


}

/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

and would like to get the last inserted id , as the table has record_num field which is auto increment .

so my question is should i place connection name or the statement name inside the function.

i.e
1)

```
echo mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

*Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php*

2)

```
echo mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);
```

*Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php*

which one is correct ? 
which one will give me last insrted id by the $stmt ?

- there are no other inserts are being done using the same stmt one the same page..*

---

**Update:**

according to the note from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php

I am doing only single insert so i guess i can use

```
mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt)
```

but while doing multiple inserts using prepared statements using

```
echo mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

is best practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use

```
mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Because of this note on the PHP manual you referred us to

**mysqli_stmt_insert_id**

> It should be noted that using mysqli_stmt->insert_id will not result in a unique ID being returned for each execution of a prepared insert statement.  In practice, it appears that the first insertion ID is returned.  If you are performing multiple inserts with the same prepared statement (one invocation of mysqli_stmt::prepare and multiple invocations of mysqli_stmt::execute() for a given statement), and need to keep the unique ID for each insert, use mysqli_connection->insert_id.

Answer (score 1):

for procedural language you need to use below code,
mysqli_insert_id($link));

yes as you mention in 1 point.

Answer (score 1):

Correct is 1) - link, as stated in documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php