# Get last inserted ID in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to get the last inserted ID for each insert operation and put it into array, I am trying to see what is the correct way of doing it.

Following this post [Which is correct way to get last inserted id in mysqli prepared statements procedural style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226740/which-is-correct-way-to-get-last-inserted-id-in-mysqli-prepared-statements-proce) 
I have tried to apply it to my code but I am still not getting the right response.

```
   if($data->edit_flag == 'ADDED')
        {

            $rowdata[0] =   $data->location_name;  
            $rowdata[1] =   0;  
            $rowdata[2] =   $data->store_id;

            $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO store_locations (location_name,total_items, store_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";

            $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($rowdata);
            $id = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($statement);
            echo "inserted id: " . $id;
        }
```

I then realised that I am using a PDO connection so obviously mysqli functions wont work. I went ahead and tried the following

```
$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
echo "insert id: " . $id;
```

but the response is still empty? What am I doing incorrectly? For the lastInsertId(), should I be using $conn or $statement from here:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($rowdata);
```

Comment: Use $conn have you looked into your database if it inserts

Comment: Yes, it insertes in the database but the value returned by lastInsertId() is 0

Comment: Note: Try and supply your query string as a direct argument to the `prepare()` function, not as a throw-away variable that's used only once. This helps misfires where you run the wrong query by accident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using lastInsertId() correctly according to the PDO:lastInsertId() documentation

```
        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($rowdata);
        $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Some potential reasons why it is not working:

1. Is this code within a TRANSACTION? If so, you need to COMMIT the transaction after the execute and before the lastInsertId()
2. Since you INSERT IGNORE there is the potential that the INSERT statement is generating an error and not inserting a row so lastInsertId() could potentially be empty.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know what I have actually done but I changed the order of my code around a bit and now it returns the last insert id without any issues. It wasn't within transaction, I tried putting the lastInsertId() before execute, then moved it after execute and it worked...

Comment: The problem is using the `mysqli` function on a PDO query. These two libraries do not inter-operate this way.

Comment: @tadman if you read the question I have mentioned that I tried mysqli first but then remembered that I am using PDO query and changed it to PDO function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pdo,

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("...");
$stmt->execute();
$lastInsId = $db->lastInsertId();
```